# How to use same tableview cell for two different tableviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, refactoring

I have two table views displayed in a tabbar controller. One shows content filtered by popularity, other by time (latest). Both has the same cell layout and currently the code is being duplicated. How to make the cell common to both `UITableViewController`? My common class is `ContentViewCell` but I am not sure how to wire the `IBOutlets` to both the classes in the storyboard.

```
class ContentViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var body: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tag: UILabel!
    // ..
}
```

At present I have, `LatestTableViewController` with

```
class LatestViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var latestTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var latestBody: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var latestAuthor: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var latestTag: UILabel!
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use XIB for tableView Cell and reuse it anywhere in the project.

http://ios-tutorial.com/custom-uitableviewcell-xib-swift-3/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can assign `ContentViewCell` to multiple `UITableViewController` if the `IBOutlet` is exactly same for both.

All you need to do is you need to assign same class to both cell and connect the `IBOutlet` again to newly assigned cell. And it will work for both.

Remember if you forgot to connect any `IBOutlet` and you are using it then it will crash. so be careful with it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that two classes can point to same `IBOutlet` cell variable?

Comment: I think you missunderstood here or I understood it wrong. Because what I understand if you want to use one `ContentViewCell` with multiple tableview because you have same design for both and you don't want to create another class for cell which will have same code.

Comment: @jsloop Agreed with this answer, it increases your code reusability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same UITableViewCell in different UIViewController. You need to use below method in cellForRowAt indexPath datasource method of UITableView.

```
func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentViewCell",for: indexPath) as! ContentViewCell
        //Set you cell here

    return cell
    }
```